# How to pass parameters to scheduled task via cfschedule?

Tags: coldfusion, quartz-scheduler

Is there any way to pass parameters or share data with a scheduled task? I understand that you can pass serializable arguments to a Quartz Job, but this seems not to be available in cfschedule. What are the options to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is just to have a .cfm file that is called by cfschedule that itself calls the CFC and passes the desired methods.

If you want a more flexible solution, I have a Scheduler.cfc that allows you to have a method called at an frequency that you want and you have even pass arguments for the method call.

http://www.bryantwebconsulting.com/blog/index.cfm/2009/2/26/Schedulercfc-10

It can be gotten here.

https://github.com/sebtools/com.sebtools/

The important thing with it is that you have to have Scheduler instantiated into Application scope and a .cfm that is called by cfschedule that runs:

If you just have one method with arguments that needs to be called frequently, then Scheduler.cfc is overkill over the simple solution, but if this is a general problem that you need to solve more frequently, then it can pay off nicely.

Comment: I ended up taking the login out of the cfc and passing the parameters in the query string. Your solution is good too, I will consider passing the cfc name as a parameters and having a cfm to instantiate it and passing the remaining arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass them on the query string of the URL attribute.

example.com/index.cfm?param1=value1&param2=param2

If your data is complex you can always serialize it to JSON before and use deserializeJSON on the receiving task.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately I am encapsulating the logic of the task in a cfc, called through the new event handler attribute.